# Android 2.3 Custom ArrayAdapter getView Method Not Being Called

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

EDIT: Solved...mostly. Calls to Lod.g(...) inside getView() are still not showing up in LogCat but everything seems to be working. Code below has been updated to working version.

My ArrayAdapter class:

```
public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

//fields
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Post> posts;

//constructor
public PostAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> posts) {
    super(context, R.layout.post_layout, R.id.title, posts);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.posts = posts;
}

//methods
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //get data item for this position
    Post post = (Post)getItem(position);
    //check if existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
    }
    //Populate views with data
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(post.getTitle());
    TextView subTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
    subTitle.setText(post.getDescription());

    //return completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return posts.size();
}
```

}

And the code where I create the ArrayAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    //Initializing feed variables
    posts = new ArrayList<>();
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, posts);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //attaching Adapter to ListView
    list.setAdapter(postAdapter);

    DatabaseReference p = database.getReference("posts");
    p.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //get reference to post
            HashMap<Object, Object> entry = (HashMap<Object, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            //convert to Post.class datatype
            Post post = new Post();
            if (entry.get("category") != null) { post.setCategory(entry.get("category").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("title") != null) { post.setTitle(entry.get("title").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("description") != null) { post.setDescription(entry.get("description").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("hasImg") != null) { post.setImg((boolean)entry.get("hasImg")); }
            if (entry.get("postKey") != null) { post.setPostKey(entry.get("postKey").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("posterID") != null) { post.setPosterID(entry.get("posterID").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("schoolID") != null) { post.setSchoolID(entry.get("schoolID").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("flagged") != null) { post.setFlagged((long)entry.get("flagged")); }
            if (entry.get("time") != null) { post.setTime((long)entry.get("time")); };

            //add to ArrayList
            posts.add(post);
            postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.d("LIST", "Post Added: Posts: " + postAdapter.getCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#List adapter is getting initialized with zero posts elements.
#list.setAdapter(postAdapter) : put into childAdded listener.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    //retrieve post data from firebase
    posts = new ArrayList<>();

    //ListView and PostAdapter
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, posts);

    DatabaseReference p = database.getReference("posts");
    p.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //get reference to post
            HashMap<Object, Object> entry = (HashMap<Object, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            //convert to Post.class datatype
            Post post = new Post();
            if (entry.get("category") != null) { post.setCategory(entry.get("category").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("title") != null) { post.setTitle(entry.get("title").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("description") != null) { post.setDescription(entry.get("description").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("hasImg") != null) { post.setImg((boolean)entry.get("hasImg")); }
            if (entry.get("postKey") != null) { post.setPostKey(entry.get("postKey").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("posterID") != null) { post.setPosterID(entry.get("posterID").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("schoolID") != null) { post.setSchoolID(entry.get("schoolID").toString()); }
            if (entry.get("flagged") != null) { post.setFlagged((long)entry.get("flagged")); }
            if (entry.get("time") != null) { post.setTime((long)entry.get("time")); };

            //add to ArrayList
            posts.add(post);
            postAdapter.add(post);

             //attaching Adapter to ListView
            list.setAdapter(postAdapter);
            Log.d("LIST", "Item count: " + postAdapter.getCount());

            postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("LIST", "Post Added: Posts: " + postAdapter.getCount());

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why calling setAdapter() every time a child is added should be necessary. I thought it was a one-and-done thing. Also I removed the call to postAdapter.add(post) because it was throwing a Null Pointer Exception and also creating duplicate entries in the postAdatper. The real problem, however, is still unresolved - getView() is still not being called.

Comment: postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this function used to notify the listview when dataset has changed. so no need to calling setAdapter inside childAdded listener.
i have same kind of problem which is resolved by calling the setAdapter when data set created,so great if it's works for you.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the problem had to do with the ContraintLayout I was using. Some tweaks to the formatting and the list showed up. I have updated the code to reflect the working implementation I have now. Interestingly, my Log.d(...) calls inside getView() still aren't showing up even though for everything to work getView *must* be getting called. Still not sure how to explain that one.